# Convert timestamp to readable date in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am fetching data from `collection`. I saved date in `timestamp` Firestore standard format. This is how I am saving `record['entryDate'] = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();`

Now when I am fetching it, I want it to be in the **readable format in a new variable in array**. This is the code I am currently using to fetch the data:

`home.ts`

```
ngOnInit {
        //start fetch
        this.crudService.read_Projects().subscribe(data => {
          this.projectList = data.map(e => {
            return {
              id: e.payload.doc.id,
              isEdit: false,
              name: e.payload.doc.data()['name'],
              desc: e.payload.doc.data()['desc'],
              followers: e.payload.doc.data()['followers'],
              milestone: e.payload.doc.data()['milestone'],
              entryDate: e.payload.doc.data()['entryDate'],

             // for each readable_entryDate =  how do i convert ?

            };
          })
          console.log(this.projectList);
        });//end fetch
}
```

`crud.service.ts`

```
  read_Projects() {
    return this.firestore.collection('projects').snapshotChanges();
  }
```

[image]

I am able to do it using `get()` but unable to do it in the above code, in case you wish to see my `get()` code for fetching and converting date to readable format:

```
 const ref = firebase.firestore().collection('cities').where('name', '==', 'JALANDHAR')
 .get()
 .then(function(querySnapshot) {
   querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
   const timeinmillsecs = doc.data().timestamp.seconds * 1000; //1. get timestamp and make it in milli
   console.log(new Date(timeinmillsecs)); // 2. convert to time lambi string
   let a1 = new Date(timeinmillsecs); // 3. convert to simple date
   let show_year_month_date =  a1.getFullYear()+'/'+(a1.getMonth()+1) +'/'+a1.getDate(); // 3.convert to imple date
   console.log(show_year_month_date); // 4. needed result // will show this on form
 });
 })
 .catch(function(error) {
     console.log("Error getting documents: ", error);
 });
```

### Edit 1

After using `ToDate()`, changing my code to

`entryDate: e.payload.doc.data()['entryDate'].toDate(),`

I am getting full JS date object, but I need only date, maybe in `entryDate2` field in my array, how can I achieve that?

Below is how date is coming now:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't necessary:

```
doc.data().timestamp.seconds * 1000
```

You can simply call [toDate()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp#todate) on a Timestamp object to get a JavaScript Date.

After that, you might want to look into using a library such as [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) to format the date according to the user's locale and preferences.

Comment: how do i use toDate() here `entryDate: e.payload.doc.data()['entryDate']`

Comment: `entryDate: e.payload.doc.data()['entryDate'].toDate(),` gives me js object, i just need date, now how do i proceed as per my code...bit confused , i want `entryDate2` with only date in my array

Comment: As I said in my answer, you could look into using momentjs to format that date.